# Android Switch flavor after in-app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I implemented In-App-Billing in my app with a window that opens and handles the transaction. If this was successful I would like to switch the flavor of the app from "free" to "pro".

How can I do that?

Comment: where is your implemented codes?

Comment: Its working fine. I just want to know how to switch from free to pro version

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "switch"? Android flavors are not meant to alter runtime behaviour: they are useful when you need to produce different APKs from the same project. If you really want a different APK for purchasing users, you should find a way to download the other APK after the purchase, for example redirecting the users to a different app page on the Play Store. Downloading a new app is maybe to complex for some users, so the easiest way to do this is to have only one APK and include all the resources in it. If you really want to redirect the users to a different Play Store page, you can do something like this:

```
String packageName = "your.paid.app.application.id";
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
}
```

This code handles also the case of users without the Play Store app on their device.

After the download of the second (paid) app, the users will have both apps installed on theirs phone.

You can find more details about flavors [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html).

If you prefer instead to manage all the logic in a single APK, you can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html).

Comment: "so the easiest way to do this is to have only one APK and include all the resources in it." Thats what I have at the moment with two different flavors

Comment: Please note that each flavor generates a different APK.

Comment: so what should i do now? link to the full version or remove the flavors?

Comment: This is your choice. You can find examples of both approaches on the Play Store.

Comment: how to do that logic in a single apk?

Comment: You can check the official guide [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) under "Querying for purchased items".